# how can show username login into label

Tags: java, mysql, javafx

I do this code for taking user login into label but is give me the last row inserted 
 i need to get the username into label 
    public void userlabel() {

```
        try {
            // Connection to the database
            Connection myConn = DB.getConnection();

            // Statement
            Statement myStmt = myConn.createStatement();
            // SQL query
    ResultSet rs = myStmt.executeQuery("select * from mr_users");
            // Result processing
            while (rs.next()) {
                // testing if it gets the data from the db
                System.out.println(rs.getString("user_id"));
//                  System.out.println(rs.getString("item_price"));

                // attempt to put it in a textfield
                co_userid.setText(rs.getString("user_id"));
//                  load_groups.setText(rs.getString("item_groups"));
            }

        } catch (Exception exc) {
        }
        }
```

Comment: `SELECT * user_id` -> remove the `*`

Comment: I don't see the point of using a select as the source of the insert.  If you already know the `user_id`, then why not just directly insert it?

Comment: mr @Tim Biegeleisen i need to  take the user id who's open the transaction and insert the record from table and insert it into another table

Comment: @waeliam88 It's not clear what you are asking. It is a problem that you can't run an `INSERT` statement to insert a new row in a table or that you can't run a `SELECT` statement to get data from a table? What do you mean by "user id who's open the transaction"? How do you open the transaction? Maybe you should [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @progman i mean i want get userid login into label or textfield

Comment: @waeliam88 Still not clear what you are asking. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] which can be compiled and tested by others, which shows where you try to read or use the userid from the user, who started the transaction.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below query

```
"INSERT INTO mr_order (co_user_id)" + "
SELECT user_id
FROM mr_users
WHERE user_id = "+"give_an_userID"
```

Comment: Mr @Pragyan  what you mean "give_an_userID" ?

Comment: The user ID which you want to extract and insert

Answer (score 0):

This is working query. Try it once.

```
INSERT INTO `transaction`(`tr_user_id`)
SELECT user_id
FROM users
WHERE user_id={USER_ID}
```

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).